# How does one change the \paragraph formatting in LaTeX

Tags: latex, paragraphs

This stems out of [How can one number paragraphs in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543208/how-can-one-number-paragraphs-in-latex), which I asked earlier today:

Running with [Brent.Longborough](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9634/brent-longborough)'s suggestion for how to number paragraphs in a document:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
...
\paragraph{If we want to}
\paragraph{do something}
```

This results in LaTeX producing something likeso:

```
0.0.0.1 If we want to 
0.0.0.2 do something
```

How can one change the numbering scheme of *\paragraph{}* to produce something like:

```
1. If we want to
2. do something
```

or alternatively

```
A. If we want to
B. do something
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if a mass migration of *tex related questions is in order.  Perhaps ask on meta?  Or do you WANT these on meta for a particular reason?

Comment: Will: You ask a good question. Since http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363 was migrated, I thought it valuable to point out the other questions that seem indistinguishable (to me) in terms of criteria for migration -- I figured they just "flew under the radar" (it since occurred to me that the TeX/LaTeX tag is probably a better way to point them out). If there is a criteria for moving *TeX questions over, I don't know what it is, but I assumed that moderators would. Perhaps Gumbo (who migrated the above question) could offer some guidance? I'll ask on Meta.

Comment: It seems this has already been discussed ad nauseum: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70466 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918 I don't feel there's much I can contribute, policy wise. I had hoped my submissions highlighted the "under the radar" *TeX questions that would be moved as part of a novel policy that hit the question in my previous comment, but alas my "flagging for migration" may have been both unnecessary and jumping the gun.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change the number referenced when referring to paragraphs, you want to change `\theparagraph`. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\roman{paragraph}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{foo} \lipsum[1]
\paragraph{bar} \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Instead of `\roman` you can also use `\Roman`, `\arabic`, `\alph`, `\Alph`. Although if you have lots of paragraphs you'll want to use the alphalph package and use \alphalph to get more than 26 paragraphs.

Note that `\paragraph` takes an argument for the "paragraph title". If you never want that, you'll probably want to define your own command to simplify things:

```
\newcommand\PARA{\paragraph{}}
```

You'll also probably want to remove the way that paragraphs are numbered "within" sections; i.e., they reset from "1" for every new section. You can get around this with something like

```
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{paragraph}{section}
\makeatother
```